# How could I show this Looping process in a flowchart?

Tags: loops, nested-loops, flowchart, nested-for-loop

I tried making it but, i couldn't understand where do I put the last if statement to be shown in the flowchart.

```
int j,i;
    
    for (i = 2; i <= 50; i++) {
        
        for (j = 2; j <= i; j++) {
            
            if(i%j==0) {
        
                break;
                
            }
            
        }
        
        if (i==j) {
            System.out.println(j);
        }           
    }
```

Comment: what is the question here? what are you trying to do what is the input what is the expected output?

Comment: @odaiwa it's a loop the output is prime number between 1 - 50.